# CSS not working after building AOT and Rollup on Angular4

Tags: angular, rollup

For some reason the css breaks after I build my app on angular 4 as AOT rollup.js

I use the same AOT configuration as: 
https://v4.angular.io/guide/aot-compiler

No compile errors, no console errors, but the css on the components or styleUrls are broken.

Any ideas? Did I miss something?

```
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-article',
      templateUrl: './article.component.html',
      styleUrls:['./article.component.css']
    })
```

**rollup-config.js**

```
        import nodeResolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
        import commonjs    from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
        import uglify      from 'rollup-plugin-uglify';

        export default {
          entry: 'src/main.js',
          dest: 'src/build.js', // output a single application bundle
          sourceMap: false,
          format: 'iife',
          onwarn: function(warning) {
            // Skip certain warnings

            // should intercept ... but doesn't in some rollup versions
            if ( warning.code === 'THIS_IS_UNDEFINED' ) { return; }

            // console.warn everything else
            console.warn( warning.message );
          },
          plugins: [
              nodeResolve({jsnext: true, module: true}),
              commonjs({
                include: 'node_modules/rxjs/**',
              }),
              uglify()
          ]
        };
```

Comment: Can you provide examples of what is broken? What does your CSS look like for the broken items?

Comment: the component css is not loading on the head of the html as webpack, is just loading a html with no style

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, the problem was the aot folder was generated outside the src folder after ran ngc or build:aot. Was wrong configuration on thets.config.aot.json

```
    -src-
        -aot-
        -app-
          components
          app.component.ts
          app.module.ts
        -assets-
        -wwwroot-
        main.ts
        main.aot.ts
        ts.config.json
        ts.config.aot.json
        index.html
```